# How to obtain full_text in twitter API search

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am using the [Standar Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets), but it does not have the new full_text for that tweets with size more than 140 characters. As mention twitter for the streamer api. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates

Does any know how to fix it?

**FYI:** I am implementing this with nodejs /search/tweets.json works for tweets but if it has more than 140 characters it is cut with "..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this parameter to your `search/tweets` request: `tweet_mode=extended`

Comment: It works!

twitter.get('/search/tweets.json', {
q: 'MyKeyword',
until:'2017-12-08T13:00:00.000Z'
count: 100,
    include_entities: 1,
tweet_mode:'extended',
}, function (error, data) {